# Adding a Header to a MATLAB figure from command prompt

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure that has several subplots. I am trying to add a header for when it prints. I can do this from the print preview, but I would like to program it in, as my code has quite a few figures.

```
figure('numbertitle','off','name','This is my window title',...
'PaperOrientation','landscape','PaperPosition',[0.25,0.25,10.5,7])

subplot(2,2,1)
plot(1:10)
title('Example subplot1')

subplot(2,2,2)
plot(10:20)
title('Example subplot2')

subplot(2,2,3)
plot(20:30)
title('Example subplot3')

subplot(2,2,4)
plot(30:40)
title('Example subplot4')
```

I found [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1PEPG8/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-1PEPG8), but it does not seem to work, nor do I totally understand what is happening there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution mentioned in your link actually works.** 
Through the Show preview dialog is a little buggy as it overrides the set header. 
You could avoid opening the dialog (wich ist probalby what you want anyway) or change the header afterwards to workaround this. You can always check the current head using:  `getappdata(gcf,'PrintHeaderHeaderSpec')`.

Just append this to your code to get a header printed:

```
%%change header
hs = getappdata(gcf,'PrintHeaderHeaderSpec');
if isempty(hs)
hs = struct('dateformat','none',...
'string','Test',...
'fontname','Times',...
'fontsize',12,... % in points
'fontweight','normal',...
'fontangle','normal',...
'margin',72); % in points
end

hs.string = 'Your Personal Header';
setappdata(gcf,'PrintHeaderHeaderSpec',hs);

%% print
print(gcf)
```

You probably also want to change the print command in a way that no human interaction is necessary anymore.